# seq2seq model transformer model - what's the best way to batchify my inputs?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, transformer-model, seq2seq

I'm trying to build a character-level model that matches diacritics for Hebrew characters (each character is decorated with a diacritic). Note that the correct diacritic is dependent on the word, the context and the part-of-speech (not trivial).

I built an LSTM based model which achieves 18% word-level accuracy (18% of the words were exactly right in all their characters, on an unseen test set)

Now I'm trying to beat that with a transformer model, following [pytorch seq-2-seq tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html), and I'm reaching far worse results (7% word-level accuracy).

My training dataset is 100K sentences, most with up to 30 characters, but some go all the way to 80 characters.

My question (finally) - what's the best way to batchify these inputs for the transformer? I prepared 30-characters chunks that cover each sentence (e.g. a 55 characters sentence => 30 + 25) and padded with zeros when a chunk is shorter than 30. I'm also trying to split the chunks between words (on spaces) and not in mid-word.

Is this the way to go? Am I missing some better (and better-known) technique?